# how can i input pdf into html using (css and html) with using any code

Tags: html, css, pdf

I don't really know how to input a pdf
I tried to use input code
and tried IMG code
and the  code that too didn't work
tried herf but don't know how to use it with pdf

Comment: What do you mean by "input a pdf"? A file upload?

Comment: Welcome to SO, it's a good practice to share your piece of code, can you please share what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method with Adobe Reader Plugin installed**

Just insert your url/path inside the src of this iframe/embed

```
<iframe src="URL" height="" width=""></iframe>
```

Or

```
<embed src="URL" height="" width=""></embed>
```

---

**Method without Adobe Reader Plugin installed**

You can use the Google Docs viewer to view documents online on your page by placing an IFrame of the viewer.

**How To Do It**

1. Upload your file on Google Drive or Google Docs
2. If on google drive, click twice on your Document to Preview
3. Click on the vertical three dot button
4. Click in open new window

[image]

5. Click again on the vertical three dot button
6. Click on "embbed item"

[image]

7. Copy the iframe code

[image]

8. Your HTML code should look something like this example:

```html
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zd4glWbGCFysTEUFExKgRAegr6scG10L/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

**To Show the PDF to everyone**

1. Click on the vertical three dot button
2. Click on Share

[image]

3. Change to **Anyone with the link Can View**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it is an is hosted in your server then add the pdf with iframe

```
<iframe src="/path/to/pdf/location/name.pdf" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the following methods,

`<embed src="URL" height="" width=""></embed>`

`<iframe src="URL" height="" width=""></iframe>`

You can read more on this topic from https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-embed-pdf-in-html.html